# Tenma 72 6800 20Mhz

Tags: oscilloscope

I'm looking to buy my first scope to help with analysis of circuits and have come across a lot of the above scopes. I have a few project on and believe I can use this scope to measure 12V to 240V wave forms is this correct?

Many thanks

Steve

Comment: Sorry, product reviews are off-topic here -- I don't know whether the moderators will make exception since you're asking about an oscilloscope. You might try asking in chat (http://chat.stackexchange.com/) may get more useful response there.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't realise. No problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general they are OK unless you are looking at small signals eg 20mV or less. I use a Rigol 1102 and it's quite reasonable, except the capacitance of the probes/amplifiers do seem to load the circuit a bit. Vastly better than nothing!

Comment: Some Rigols can be hacked to perform like the next model up, worth bearing in mind when buying.